# Where can I find a version of current using GCC compiler on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, llvm

I use a command: `g++ -v` to know what's the version of GCC currently using. But I get following output:

```
$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

So I don't understand. Am I using LLVM or GCC when I compile my program with: `g++ test.cpp`? Why do I see the information about LLVM when I'm requesting the information about GCC? LLVM used with Clang as a frontend.
What have I missed there?

Comment: try g++ --version?

Comment: try to see if g++ is an alias on linux you can use 'alias  g++'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you are using Apple's LLVM pretending to be gcc/g++. This is not a huge problem. One place where I was annoyed enough was the fact that gcc's `-march=native` optimizations just do not work with LLVM which resulted in about 50% worse performance in a rather CPU-intensive program I was running.

Getting a full `gcc` based toolchain installed involves a lot of work. See [Compiling GCC 6 on macOS Sierra](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/22/compiling-gcc-6-macos/) and [Compiling GCC 6 on OS X](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/05/10/compiling-gcc-6-mac-os-x/).

If you get the real thing working, you might also want to build dedicated GNU binutils etc.

Comment: Is getting a full GCC installation difficult?  Other than the long build-time I've never had problems with `brew install gcc`. The one caveat I'm aware of with Homebrew's GCC is that it doesn't install to the `PATH` to avoid conflicts. That's easy enough to change of course.

Comment: Difficult, no. Tedious, yes. It is not something I look forward to when new versions come out. Also, I helped a few friends track down problems due to build tools inadvertently using Apple utilities with the genuine gcc etc. Not fun.

Answer (score 3):

You're using LLVM. Unless you've specifically installed GCC (e.g. with Homebrew) you don't have GCC installed. References to GCC on your system are aliases to Clang intended to allow most code to compile without problems.